# How can i set the background of a grid?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Im playing around with styles, and want to set the background of the Grid, something like this:

```
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Background.png" />
        </Style>
```

But this does not work, what is the correct way... and how could I do it like I do it with classes in css as I want it to affect every Grid, the one the wraps the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the background property directly like so.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle1}">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/BackgroundImage.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

If you want to create a style resource, you can set the value like so

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BackgroundImage.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle1}"/>
```

I recommend using Expression Blend to help you to discover how to work with styles.  It will generate control templates for you so you can see how they are structured.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/myimage.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```